# How to calculate duration of two different of two date in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I prefer to calculate date time in Codeigniter as below description

I select date from database with two different duration

1. From_date = 2014-11-30,
2. To_date   = 2014-12-03,

I want to get result as below.

duration = **from_date**-**To_date**

**duration = ?**

```
<?php 
    $exp = date("y-m-d",strtotime($invoice->fto));
    $now = date("y-m-d",time());
    $diffday = $now-$exp;
    echo $diffday;
?>
```

As above code I get only **0**

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to calculate the difference between two dates using PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/676824/how-to-calculate-the-difference-between-two-dates-using-php)

Comment: [Google](https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=92p4VNqpDoLW8ge8jYCQCA&gws_rd=ssl#q=How+to+calculate+duration+of+two+different+of+two+date+in+php)

Answer (score 0):

CodeIgniter has a helper function, that will do this for you, within the date helper. Called "timespan"

https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/date_helper.html

```
echo timespan($exp, $now);
```